# What could go wrong if two Infinity Stones were kept in the same Realm?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

From mid-credit scene of *Thor: The Dark World* movie:

> Sif: You know why we're here.
>   The Collector (Taneleer Tivan): Of course. But, if I
>   may ask, why not keep it secure in your own vault?
>   Volstagg: **The
>   Tesseract is already on Asgard. It is not wise to keep two Infinity
>   Stones so close together.**

Why was it not wise to keep two Infinity Stones in Asgard? What could be the consequences?

Comment: I seem to remember in the comics the Hood had been trying to assemble the Infinity Gems for himself, and with each one he aquired their proximity to each other seemed to increase their respective powers, as well as increasing their abilities when combined.  I can't remember off the top of my head where this happened though.

Answer (score 4):

The infinity stones appear to be analogs of the Infinity Gems, which are objects of incredible power in the main "616" marvel comics universe.  When they are combined together, the gems become the Infinity Gauntlet, which grants its weilder omnipotence.

In the late 1980s, Thanos assembled the gauntlet in a comic series of the same name, and used its power to, among other things, kill half the sentient life in the universe and curb-stomp every hero, villain, or cosmic entity that tried to oppose him.

Comment: Doesn't Infinity Gauntlet thing happen with *all six* Infinity Gems? I don't think its valid with two Infinity Stones.

Comment: With two infinity stones, you get preferred seating at select sporting events and a personal concierge. But it's not all rainbows and unicorns, an unscrupulous person could use two infinity stones to (just for instance) cause vending machines to spontaneously go "out of order" or even cause the neighbor's dog to start barking at 3am. It gets progressively worse, the more stones that are added. A person with four stones could cause traffic jams on the freeway that last no less than six hours or the TSA to start allowing no more than 3 ounces of "solid" into any carry-on luggage.

Comment: @SachinShekhar, the "infinity guantlet thing" requires six, yes. But each stone is incredibly powerful in its own right. Each one grants incredible power. Look at what happened with just one - the Tesseract. Keeping two together, so that they could be stolen together is just an incredibly stupid idea.

Comment: Two stones being together is twice the prize for someone knocking over just one cosmic vault.  It would be a kind of "please attack me first" prize.  (and even apart, the gems gave an absurd amount of power.  Odin may have just been being prudent.)

Comment: `Keeping two together, so that they could be stolen together is just an incredibly stupid idea.` ~> :D This reasoning is awesome, but (in case you are serious) it shouldn't be the case because Asgardians are super confident against any type of enemy.

Comment: the same asgardians who have been attacked and sacked twice in recent memory?

Comment: Being super confident is not the same as being invincible or being foolish enough to think that there is no way they could possibly be defeated.

Comment: The Asgardians have had their confidence rattled after the events in the last couple movies. Prior to the first Thor movie they likely would have kept both.

Comment: And it should be noted Doug's use of the term omnipotence isn't really an exaggeration....

Answer (score -6):

Each [Infinity Gem/Stone](http://marvel.wikia.com/Infinity_Gems) possesses an individual "talent." Combining the talents of multiple stones would result in unexpected behaviours. Each stone is also represented by color.

For example: If someone had obtained the Blue MIND Gem/Stone and then used it in combination with. for example the Orange TIME Gem/Stone this could potentially enable the possessor to travel through TIME with only the power of their MIND.

Throw in the Purple "Tesseract"/Cosmic Cube/Space Gem/Stone and you've got a combo that might permit someone to use their MIND to move through both SPACE and TIME.

Also, we've seen that individuals can fall under the control of the Infinity Gem/Stones. Jane Foster was infused with the Red "Aether"/POWER Gem/Stone, and numerous S.H.I.E.L.D. agents fell under Loki's control after being touched with his staff, which appears to contain the Blue MIND Gem/Stone.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately we're not a discussion forum, we're a Q&A site. We generally look for answers to be based on definitive facts and references, or at the very least be well reasoned based on available evidence. I'm not familiar enough with the work to know how relevant what you've posted is, but the last part about the question to ponder definitely isn't suitable in an answer. If you think it's an interesting question that's worth asking, you can do precisely that: ask it as its own separate question.

Comment: Mind Gem hasn't been featured in Marvel's Cinematic Universe yet. Loki used another thing..

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - I agree. Much of this seems to be a quality answer but in the current "chatty" format, it's unsuitable for this site.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Actually, given that Lokis "glowing stick of destiny" allowed him to mind control humans, people have taken that as a strong hint whatever was in the staff was the mind infinity gem.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Mind control thing wasn't hidden from Thor. If it was an Infinity Stone, it'd become a hot thing in Earth-19999.

Comment: @Darryl - The site is largely 'moderated' by other users; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour