# Why were the Asgardians willing to entrust the Aether to its new owner?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world, infinity-stones

At the end of Thor: Dark World (post-credit scene),

> The Asgardians entrust an infinity stone to the Collector.

**Why? Who is this guy?** Why would Asgard, a powerhouse of the nine realms and a fairly self-righteous "nation", leave one of the most dangerous items in existence to a guy that looks like a more-unhinged Doc Brown?

To clarify, I'm not asking why Asgardians didn't want to keep it on Asgard (that was answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49519/what-could-go-wrong-if-two-infinity-stones-were-kept-in-the-same-realm)), but why would they trust it to this random person?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield It is definitely a spoiler.  Related Meta Question: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/whats-wrong-with-this-title-construction

Comment: In order to be a collector of such success and renown, you must have a potent security system.  There's always the risk that he'll *use* it, but as a collector, he's unlikely to give it away or have it stolen.

Comment: “looks like a more-unhinged Doc Brown”. Or [Will Ferrell in Zoolander](http://media.comicbook.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/will-ferrel-zoolander.jpg).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is largely a nod to the Taneleer Tivan [of the comics](http://marvel.com/universe/Collector_%28Taneleer_Tivan%29), who is similar, and more fleshed out, but with a few important differences.

While the MCU version of Tivan portrays him as just an eccentric collector so far, the comics version has a personal mission of collecting artifacts and subjects and keeping them safe so that the Universe could be repopulated.  Marvel Universe explains:

> Determined not to succumb to his wife's malady, the Collector meditated upon what he might do to give his life meaning. In a vision, he foresaw that beings of great power would arise one day determined to destroy all life in the universe. To prevent this from happening, he decided to devote his life to collecting living beings and artifacts from throughout the known universe, and placing them in safekeeping. As a fail safe if what he foresaw came to pass, he could repopulate the universe and bequeath to them the knowledge and culture of the past.

Tivan has been a villain at times, but has also worked on the side of good at others.

Not only does Tivan have a personal mission to keep all of these artifacts safe, he also has ten heavily guarded museum worlds, as well as a ship that remains in hyperspace almost all of the time to avoid being detected. Additionally, he has "temporal assimilator" which can be used for limited time-travel.

And, like I said, it's largely a nod to the comics, as in the comics, Tivan possessed the Reality Gem (though, he did not know of the gem's true powers at the time), until it was taken by Thanos.

Comment: it's also pretty clear from that scene that the Asgardians know all about him; presumably he must have the same reputation for keeping things safe in the MCU, if they chose to bring the stone to him.

Comment: +1 This makes a lot more sense from the perspective of the comics. If you've only watched the MCU movies, it appears to be more of a Doc Brown situation.

Comment: And then this A holes go and ruin his reputation in an hour.

Comment: Wasn't the Guardians' fault; it was Carina's. Interestingly, Carina is the name of his daughter in the comics.